# Simple if elif mismatched result

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

This `if`-`elif` is simple and straightforward. index is a 1-D array with values of `0`-`5` only. As you can see from the image, the only correct `if`-`elif` is only for `index[i]==0` and `index[i]==1`. For `index[i]==5`, it was supposed to print **`f`** but the result was printed as **`d`**. What went wrong?

Current output:

[image: screenshot of output]

```
for i in index:
    print(i)
    if index[i]==0:
      print(" :a")
    elif index[i]==1:
        print(" :b")
    elif index[i]==2:
        print(" :c")
    elif index[i]==3:
        print(" :d")
    elif index[i]==4:
        print(" :e")
    elif index[i]==5:
        print(" :f")
```

Comment: what is the index value?

Comment: is it the type? if it's the type it is integers

Comment: i mean, what is value, you have assigned to index in for loop?

Comment: `i` loops over _values_, not indices of `index`! You just need `i` instead of `index[i]`.

Comment: Probably not the best dupe target but this is basic python behaviour.

Comment: @AndrasDeak oh i see! Thanks! That solved the problem

Comment: But if you have a scalar index from 0 to 5 you can drop the ifs and use `'abcdef'[i]`.

Comment: How do I do that? Is it as below?
for i in index:
    print(i)
    'abcdef'[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just shorten your code by avoiding those `if` `elif`s using a dictionary to map to required values:

```
index = [1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 0]
map_dict = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d", 4: "e", 5: "f"}

for i in index:
    print(map_dict.get(i))

# b
# f                                                        
# f                                                      
# f                                                        
# f                                                         
# e                                                  
# e                                                      
# e                                                       
# a
```

**EDIT**:

To get count of each of the item in the output:

```
from collections import Counter

index = [1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 0]
map_dict = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d", 4: "e", 5: "f"}

lst = []
for i in index:
    value = map_dict.get(i)
    print(value)
    lst.append(value)

print(Counter(lst))
```

Comment: is it possible to count the totals of  each 'a', 'b','c','d', 'e' and 'f' of the output?

because in if elif, i can just use countera+=1 etc

Comment: @Projia `collections.Counter(index)` to get the counts of each index, then use the above dict to get the count of characters.

Comment: See the edit now.

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak and theausome. It seems that dictionaries are very convenient and straightforward. Will learn more on it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and the issue is related to the fact that in each loop you have some confusion between the index and the value.

Here, using enumerate, I can access both index and value at every loop:

```
index_list = [10,4,2,3,4,15,7]

for index, value in enumerate(index_list):
    print "\nCurrent index: " + str(index)
    print "Current value: " + str(value)
    print "Current result:"
    if value==0:
        print(" :a")
    elif value==1:
        print(" :b")
    elif value==2:
        print(" :c")
    elif value==3:
        print(" :d")
    elif value==4:
        print(" :e")
    elif value==5:
        print(" :f")
    else:
        print("This value is not in the 0 - 5 range, skipping it...")
```

Comment: You're just making the same mistake as OP. Try with `index = [10,11,12]` etc.

Comment: Correct indeed!
Should be working now

Comment: Nope, sorry. As I said, try with test values starting from 10.

Comment: @AndrasDeak
The OP is writing:  "with values of 0-5 only"

Comment: The code still only doesn't fail by accident :) Like driving on the wrong side of the highway when there's no other car on the road.

Comment: I don't get it...
How can you make the code fail if the provided array is only as in the requirements?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think I've understood :D Thanks :)

Comment: Can you spot a difference between your code and OP's code? That's the error!

Comment: @theausome It should be ok now :)

Comment: Yup. Now only a style remark: use `val` everywhere if you have it :)

Comment: Fully agreed, @AndrasDeak.
I've now improved the style as you pointed out and added a few debug prints.
My pig now has lipstick too :D

Thanks for the suggestions and the patience.